# C# Retrieving Screen Update Rectangle

Tags: c#, screen, user32

I am trying to create a program that makes lots of screenshots in succession. Instead of re-creating the screenshots over and over, I only want to find the changes between screens.

To do this I used the GetUpdateRect() method on a screen-level. Unfortunately it does not give me correct data. As I'm relatively new to C#, I'm sure I did something wrong :P

This code should log all the screen changes, but instead it returns [0,0,0,0]:

```
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetDesktopWindow();
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern bool GetUpdateRect(IntPtr hWnd, out Rectangle lpRect, bool bErase);

    static void Main()
    {
        Rectangle updateRect;
        GetUpdateRect(GetDesktopWindow(), out updateRect, false);
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            Console.WriteLine(updateRect);
        }
    }
```

All help is greatly appreciated! :D

Comment: I think `System.Drawing.Rectangle` doesn't use the same layout as `RECT`. You may need to define your own struct.

Comment: GetWindowRect(GetDesktopWindow(), out updateRect); works fine, so I'm guessing the same rules apply for GetUpdateRect().

Comment: Hard to see the point of this.  The desktop window is invariably covered by windows of other applications.  So there is never a reason to update it.  Especially so when Aero is enabled.  If this is an attempt to create a screen recorder or a remote desktop style app then you are not close with this.

Comment: Hans, in the final program Aero is disabled. This is only a small snapshot of the problem I face. One of the windows it must be able to capture is the desktop and any other drawing functions related to it. I already have a working version of a powerful remote assistance program, however, I wish to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the code listed [on Pinvoke.Net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/RECT.html) to import the `RECT` type instead of using `System.Drawing.Rectangle` (as @Alvin Wong suggests) and changing the signature of the `GetUpdateRect()` method to match.

HTH